# Show that $V=\operatorname{Im}f\oplus\operatorname{Im}g$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let both $f:V\to V$ and $g:V\to V$ be idempotent linear operators. I'm asked to show that if $f+g:V\to V$ is the identity map then $V=\operatorname{Im}f\oplus\operatorname{Im}g$.

I'm happy showing that $V=\operatorname{Im}f+\operatorname{Im}g$.

I know I now need to show that $\operatorname{Im}f \cap \operatorname{Im}g=\{0\}.$

How do I do this?

Comment: If nonzero $v\in \operatorname{Im} f\cap \operatorname{Im}g$ then $f(v)=g(v)=v$. Get a contradiction with identity of $f+g$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to show that $f\circ g$ is the zero map when $f+g$ is the identity and $f$ and $g$ are idempotent.  For then, if $v = f(v') = g(v'')$ then $f(v) = f(v') = 0$.  But $f(v')=v$.

Answer (score 0):

I follows from this simple fact:

> If $P:V\to V$ is an idempotent linear operator then:
>
> 1. $I-P$ is an idempotent linear operator
> 2. $\operatorname{Im}P=\ker(I-P)$, or similarly, $\ker P=\operatorname{Im}(I-P)$.

If you need help to prove it, see this :

> Indeed, the first affirmation goes by the following computation $(I-P)^2=I-2P+P^2=I-2P+P=I-P$. For the second one, observe that $v\in\operatorname{Im}P\iff Pv=v\iff(I-P)v=0\iff v\in\ker(I-P).$ Replace $P$ by $I-P$, then we get $\ker P=\operatorname{Im}(I-P)$.

Let $f:V\to V$ be an idempotent linear operator. Then an ordinary exercise shows that
$$V=\operatorname{Im}f\oplus\ker f=\operatorname{Im}f\oplus\operatorname{Im}(I-f)=\operatorname{Im}f\oplus\operatorname{Im}g$$
where we denote $g=I-f$.